# How to set up a Many-To-One Relation in Doctrine?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm setting up a new database in Doctrine and I want to use a `Many-To-One` relation. 
The database works great, but I can't use queries with these classes.

I followed these documentations:

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table
 **/
class Section
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     **/
     protected $id;

     //... 

     /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Manufacturer")
     */
    private $manufacturer;

    //...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 **/
class Manufacturer
{   
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     **/
    protected $id;  
    //...
}
```

So my problem is, that I can't use any queries with `Section`.

To test, I've this small procedure:

```
$relation = 'Section';

$rep = $entityManager->getRepository($relation); //here is the problem

$result = $rep->findAll();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row->getName();
}
```

If I change `$relation` to `'Manufacturer'` it is working, or If I use another relation (`One-To-One` or `Many-To-Many`), it is also fine. But I'cant use a `Many-To-One` (or `One-To-Many bidirectional` either). 
Manual DQL-Queries doesn't work.

I'm sitting for more than two days on this problem, hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

To get a repository with doctrine, you have to pass the name of a Doctrine Entity. I know two way for doing that (related to your case) :

```
use App\Entity\Section;

$rep = $entityManager->getRepository(Section::class);

$rep = $entityManager->getRepository("App\Entity\Section"); // Path is depending of your application's structure
```

Comment: i think it is done by the autoload.php? Why I dont have to do it with Manufacturer?

Comment: Maybe you miss an use directive (use App\Entity\Section) in your controller ?

Comment: But why I've to Do it manually? I dont do it with Manufacturers either. But there it is working. I can not try it out now, but it shouldn't be the problem I guess :s

Comment: If there is already a use directive for Manufacturer (use App\Entity\Manufacturer;) at the top of controller then you can just write $entityManager->getRepository("Manufacturer"); . Else you have to write $entityManager->getRepository("App\Entity\Manufacturer");

Comment: I dont have an use directive for any entity. I just have this: $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode); And in $paths, there are my php files for the entities. So If I do " $entityManager->getRepository("Manufacturer") it is working, but not for  $entityManager->getRepository("Section")...